# Is it ok to have two Table Views on the same window/view as master-detail concept on iPad?

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a `UITabBar` in my iPad app, and I need to have a Master-Detail concept on one of my `UITabBar`views.

I can't use `UISplitViewController` because Apple says:

```
 The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the root view
 of your  application window. You should never present a split view inside of 
 a navigation or tab bar interface.
```

Is it ok to have two `UITableViews` on same view as Master-Detail concept on iPad? Is there any other approach for this idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any limitation about having two table views in a tab. I'd approach it like this:

- for that tab, have an overall UIViewController that can run things when the user switches to that tab
- it sets up the master detail table views as appropriate.